# C# KeyDown alphanumeric culture dependent !

Tags: c#, keyboard, culture

How to determine if the pressed `Key` is an alphabetical key 
regard to the **culture specific keys**:

e.g.:

`'[' = 'ú' = 'ü'` ... is the same key but with different value on different language Keyboards.

I've tried to compare the ordinal key value: (int)e.Key >= 0x20E ..and <= ..
but it does not work well, as modifier keys have sometimes same ordinal codes.

Any idea?
Thanks

**EDITED:**

Hmm and how about this ?

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex objAlphaNumericPattern = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
            if (!objAlphaNumericPattern.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString()))      
            {
                lp.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Maybe there is a different way to achieve what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score -1):

Is `char.IsLetter` method helpful in your case?

```
char.IsLetter('['); //Return false
char.IsLetter('ú'); //Return true
```

With your sample, we can write:

```
if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit((char)e.Key))
{
    lp.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: e.Key is a virtual key code, not a char. Although for ASCII characters it will usually be the same value, it's not true as soon as you're outside the 0-127 range